# 'for each' is not a member of std. C++11 support already enabled

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans, std, codeblocks

The code from my professor's homework assignment is as follows. This is straight out of the box, I have not modified my professor's code. There is more to the program, but this is where the error happens. Problem line in bold.

```
std::cout << "\nAll remaining courses with enrollments:\n";
allCourses = WSUCourse::getAllCourses();
std::for_each(
  allCourses.begin(),
  allCourses.end(),
  WSUCoursePrinter());
```

I receive the following error.

```
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o main.cpp
main.cpp: In member function 'void WSUStudentPrinter::operator()(const WSUStudent*)':
main.cpp:26:20: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
       std::cout << std::to_string(studentPtr->getUniqueID()) <<
                    ^
main.cpp: In function 'void test()':
main.cpp:162:4: error: 'for_each' is not a member of 'std'
    std::for_each(
    ^
main.cpp:174:4: error: 'for_each' is not a member of 'std'
    std::for_each(
    ^
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:84: recipe for target 'build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o' failed
```

To summarize it, it's exactly like the title. `"'For each' is not a member of std"`
I have already enabled standard 11 support in all the IDE's I have compiled it in. On code blocks I put the argument in the compiler settings, in netbeans I changed it under project properties on the compiler, even the linux system on the school's network won't run it, with the same error, and I used the standard 11 inclusion line.

Ideas on how to fix this, anyone? It used to give me the same error for all locations.

Comment: Did you include `algorithm`?

Comment: Thank you so much. You have NO idea how long I have been working on this assignment. The teacher's code was broken right out of the box. How do I mark you as the answered comment?

Comment: I re-wrote the comment to an answer, you can click on the tick mark near the answer if the answer solves your problem. If your question still remains answered, you can edit your question to receive more/better answers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After being confirmed from the comment:

You forgot to include `#include<algorithm>`. Include the required header to make the symbol `foreach` included in `std` namespace and thus visible for the rest of the program.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is purely C++98, a possible C++11 solution would look like that:

```
std::cout << "\nAll remaining courses with enrollments:\n";
for (auto & course : WSUCourse::getAllCourses())
{
    //whatever WSUCoursePrinter does.
    course.print() ;
}
```

I like this way a lot more and it doesn't need the algorithm header.

Comment: "_A_ C++11 solution", not "_the_ C++11 solution" ;)